# Rasterio ValueError

Tags: python, clip, rasterio, landsat, valueerror

I am trying to clip a bunch of Landsat images with vector mask, but the Rasterio keeps hitting me with following error:

**ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence**

I have not been able to resolve it.The function for clipping I use is:

```
def clipimage(maskPath, inputBand, outImgPath):
    with fiona.open(maskPath, "r") as shapefile:
        shape = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]

    with rasterio.open(inputBand) as src:   
        out_image, out_transform = mask(dataset=src, shapes=shape, crop=True, nodata=0)
        out_meta=src.meta.copy() 
    
    out_meta.update({
        "driver":"Gtiff",
        "height":out_image.shape[1], # height starts with shape[1]
        "width":out_image.shape[2], # width starts with shape[2]
        "transform":out_transform
    })

             
    with rasterio.open(outImgPath,'w',**out_meta) as dst:
        dst.write(out_image)

return 

################################

INPUT_FOLDER = path_to_input_folder
OUTPUT_PATH = path_to_output_folder
MASK = path_to_gpkg_mask

for dir, subdirs_in_dir, files_in_dir in os.walk(INPUT_FOLDER, topdown = False):
try:
    sensingDate = os.path.basename(dir).split('_')[3]
except IndexError:       
    break

output_day_folder = os.path.join(OUTPUT_PATH, sensingDate)

os.makedirs(output_day_folder, exist_ok = True)

for file in files_in_dir:
    if 'MTL.json' in file:
        shutil.copy2(os.path.join(dir, file), output_day_folder)
        break

for file in files_in_dir:
    if file.endswith('.TIF'):
        CLIPPED_IMG_PATH = os.path.join(output_day_folder, 'clipped2_' + os.path.basename(file))
        clipimage(MASK, os.path.join(dir, file), CLIPPED_IMG_PATH)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the mask in the shapefile doesn't overlap with the image?

From the documentation of [rasterio.mask](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.mask.html#rasterio.mask.mask):

> If shapes do not overlap the raster and crop=True, a ValueError is raised. Otherwise, a warning is raised.

Comment: Rasterio won't reproject the shapefile when masking so if it's in a different coordinate reference system (CRS) to the image, it won't overlap even if it looks like it does in a GIS like QGIS that reprojects on the fly.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I am sure that both my layers are in the same EPSG as this was the first thing I have thought of.

Comment: @Catallena Have you tried using `crop=False` to check if you get warnings instead of the ValueError in that case?